# conditionally add load_balancer to aws_ecs_service in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

How can I conditionally add additional load_balancer to a aws_ecs_service resource in terraform 0.11.7?

### ternary tricks

I can use a ternary for some scenarios - like this where I add an additional sg only if defined

```
security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.host_type.id}",
    "${"" != var.additional_sg ? var.additional_sg : aws_security_group.host_type.id}",
]
```

This results in either host_type.id, additiona_sg or host_type.id, host_type.id.  It works reasonably well for a certain class of parameter.

### Additional LB problem

In this case I have two classes of services, some need to register with multiple LB and some do not.  Because this is a new requirement I don't want to switch to a new module as that will force a destroy/recreate which is more costly to deploy.  Ideally, I'd like TF to modify in place.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "default" {
  name = "${var.service_name}"
  cluster = "${var.ecs_cluster_arn}"
  ...
  load_balancer {
    container_port = "${var.container_port}"
    container_name = "${var.env_name}-${var.service_name}"
    target_group_arn = "${var.lb_target_group_arn}"
  }

  load_balancer {
    container_port = "${var.internal_container_port}"
    container_name = "${var.env_name}-${var.service_name}"
    target_group_arn = "${var.internal_lb_target_group_arn}"
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no possibility of upgrading to 0.12 or 0.13?

Comment: I've added the `terraform0.11` tag to your question. If you can accept a Terraform 0.12 or higher answer then it may be worth editing your question to remove the requirement on 0.11 and also the tag I just added.

Comment: Also there isn't a good solution to your 2 requirements. If you can upgrade to Terraform 0.12 then you can use `dynamic` blocks to have multiple load balancers. If not then you'd need to conditionally select different `aws_ecs_service` resources with different amounts of load balancers. This change would mean that the services that need to use the different resource would require recreating or the state to be moved to match it. You basically need to pick which one is easier for you to adopt.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend upgrading to Terraform 0.12. A tactical change to add the extra conditional resource now and move the state around to prevent the destroy and recreate would have to be undone when you move to Terraform 0.12 at a later date and allowing you to refactor to use `dynamic` blocks, giving you twice the work to do here as well as the work to move to Terraform 0.12 anyway.

Comment: Upgrading to 0.12 is planned but it is not an option here.  So, it looks like I need to do state surgery